# Как правильно передать соль с клиента на сервер и обратно при шифровании?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

В качестве сервера использую ASP.NET WebApi 2.
В качестве клиента универсальное приложение на Windows 10
Везде используется NET.Framework 4.6
Данные пересылаются по http.

Для шифрования использую PCLCrypto
https://github.com/aarnott/pclcrypto

Ниже класс для шифрования:

```
public static class Crypto
{
    public static byte[] CreateSalt(uint lengthInBytes)
    {
        return WinRTCrypto.CryptographicBuffer.GenerateRandom(lengthInBytes);
    }

    public static byte[] CreateDerivedKey(string password, byte[] salt, int keyLengthInBytes = 32, int iterations = 10000)
    {
        byte[] key = NetFxCrypto.DeriveBytes.GetBytes(password, salt, iterations, keyLengthInBytes);
        return key;
    }

    public static byte[] EncryptAes(string data, string password, byte[] salt)
    {
        byte[] key = CreateDerivedKey(password, salt);

        ISymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider aes = WinRTCrypto.SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithm.AesEcbPkcs7);
        ICryptographicKey symetricKey = aes.CreateSymmetricKey(key);
        var bytes = WinRTCrypto.CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(symetricKey, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));
        return bytes;
    }

    public static string DecryptAes(byte[] data, string password, byte[] salt)
    {
        byte[] key = CreateDerivedKey(password, salt);

        ISymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider aes = WinRTCrypto.SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithm.AesEcbPkcs7);
        ICryptographicKey symetricKey = aes.CreateSymmetricKey(key);
        var bytes = WinRTCrypto.CryptographicEngine.Decrypt(symetricKey, data);
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
}
```

Шифрую на клиенте логин и пароль пользователя перед отправкой:

```
var salt = Crypto.CreateSalt(16);
var bytes = Crypto.EncryptAes(data, pass, salt);
```

Расшифровываю на сервере:

```
var str = Crypto.DecryptAes(bytes, pass, salt);
```

Когда тестил в одном приложении то все работало. Как только разнес части на сервер и клиент, то возникли трудности при конвертировании `byte[]` в `string` и обратно. использовал `Convert.ToString()` и `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes`/`GetString`. При использовании этих функций получается разные значения в массиве байт.

Нашел такой пример:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472906/converting-a-string-to-byte-array-without-using-an-encoding-byte-by-byte?lq=1

Использовал первый ответ:

```
    static byte[] GetBytes(string str)
    {
        var bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        return bytes;
    }

    static string GetString(byte[] bytes)
    {
        var chars = new char[bytes.Length / sizeof(char)];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, chars, 0, bytes.Length);
        return new string(chars);
    }
```

На одной машине работает. Но в комментариях к данном ответу что-то сказано что данный способ будет работать только на одной машине. Возможности проверить на разных машинах нет. Про SSL знаю, но использовать его пока не буду.

Соль передаю вместе с зашифрованным текстом так она генерируется каждый раз при шифровании. Вроде это (новая генерация соли) увеличивает шансы от взломала методом перебора по радужным таблицам или как то так.

Скажите пожалуйста, в рамках одной версии net.framework но на разных устройствах этот код будет работать? Правильно ли будут происходить преобразования со строками? И может есть более универсальные решения?

Comment: Хм. Я, конечно, не спец в криптографии, но _зачем_ передавать соль с клиента на сервер? Пусть она себе лежит всё время на сервере.

Comment: В вопросе, который вы цитируете, обсуждается конвертация строки в набор байтов без кодировки (то есть, в кодировке по умолчанию данной машины, т. к. строку в байты без указания кодировки превратить, разумеется, невозможно). Кодируйте по-человечески, с кодировкой, проблем не будет.

Comment: Вам надо задуматься не об абстрактном "способе передачи", а о *формате передачи*. Как этот массив байт будет выглядеть. Если вы выберете формат base64 - то нужные методы уже есть в классе Convert.

Answer (score 2):

По поводу кодировки +1 VladD. Далее, мне кажется, что вы неправильно строите логику работы проверки пароля. Клиент- Сервер предполагает следующий набор(клиент- канал связи - сервер - место хранения паролей). Вы генерируете соль на клиенте, затем шифруете пароль и передает соленый массив байт по http, но на стороне сервера в дешифратор вы передаете пароль и соль? Как они туда попадают? Вы хотели сделать зашифрованный канал связи?
Что касается хранения паролей на сервере в базе,  есть решение BCrypt https://bcrypt.codeplex.com
Чтобы организовать проверку пароля на сервере вы с клиента должны передавать реальный пароль на сервере хешировать и солить его(на сервере) и сравнивать с хешом в базе(так как в базе пароль не хранится, а хранится только хеш и соль по которым вы можете определить его "правильность"). И соль нужна для того чтобы исключить взлом по уже  известным  хешам(сформированных из популярных паролей).

```
   class Crypto
{
    class User
    {
        public string Salt { get; set; }
        public string Hash { get; set; }
    }

    public static User GetUserByAddingToDatabse(string pass)
    {
        return new User()
        {
            Salt = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.GenerateSalt() + "Y87^&*(",
            Hash = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword(pass, this.Salt)
        };
    }

    public static bool Verify(string hash, string password)
    {
        return BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(hash, password);
    }
}
```

Comment: В .NET есть родной способ хэширования паролей с солью, без притягивания стороннего BCrypt - Rfc2898DeriveBytes, http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/546028/177221

Answer (score 2):

Для реализации безопасной передачи данных между клиентом и сервером есть - шифрования - есть готовый https. Он в разы надежнее хитроумных кастомных реализаций. Просто включите его на сервере.

Для проверки пароля без хранения его в открытом виде - хэширования - есть [`Rfc2898DeriveBytes`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/546028/177221). Он позволяет сгенерировать хэш с солью в виде одной строки, без привлечения сторонних библиотек.