# Как зашифровать пароли?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

На сайте есть регистрация. После регистрации все данные о пользователе попадают в таблицу Users. Так же туда кладётся пароль в виде обычной строки, что неправильно. Как мне его зашифровать?

Comment: Какой уровень защиты вы хотите? Что потенциально может украсть "хакер" ?

Comment: MD5 пароля передавайте, это самый простой вариант

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик автор же пишет, что хранение пароля не устраивает. При чем тут "передавайте".

Comment: @Monk MD5 пароля

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик и в базе хранить md5 всмысле? Так толку то, тогда злоумышленник перехватывает и передает md5, не зная пароля, толку от защиты ноль.

Comment: а есть какой-нибудь пример шифрования пароля через MD5?

Comment: @Monk вариантов тьма, к паролю цеплять гуид, полученный клиентом от сервера, вычислять MD5 и передавать его. Каждый раз при логине формируется новый гуит. Профитю.

Comment: md5 - не для шифров. Лучше бы сказали, что может украсть хакер, от которого вы защищаетесь.

Comment: мне достаточно просто того чтобы хакер не видел явно мой пароль в бд. Например вместо "password" он видел "as123d123ksaj43dkl"

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4037/storing-passwords-in-a-secure-way-in-a-sql-server-database/

Comment: @AndrewTarasevich тогда вам достаточно MD5 на сервере при записи в базу + https. А не самописного md5 на клиенте + самописной системы шифрования при передаче на сервер, как предполагает выбранный вами ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал это с помощью этого метода:

```
public string CalculateMD5Hash(string input)
    {
        // step 1, calculate MD5 hash from input
        MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
        byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
        byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);
        // step 2, convert byte array to hex string
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(hash[i].ToString("X2"));
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Это вот прямо очень плохое решение. MD5 для нынешнего времени очень слаб для хеширования паролей (и по меркам 2016 года тоже)

Answer (score 14):

## Хэширование vs Шифрование.

Для начала надо понять, что хэширование - это не шифрование. Хэшрование пароля на клиенте никак не заменяет шифрование, и никак не позволяет защититься от перехвата траффика. При передаче и пароля/его хэша (если очень хочется написать велосипед на JS) **никак** не заменяет шифрование. Вам **стоит** использовать HTTPS. Все остальные способы, включая самописное ассиметричное шифрование - **ненадежны**.

## Хэширование пароля

Хэширование защищает только от утечки данных из базы. Основная проблема при такой утечке - возможность восстановить пароли по хэшу и использовать их для password reuse attack - попытаться зайти с тем же email/username/password на популярные сервисы. Например, [на Github](https://github.com/blog/2190-github-security-update-reused-password-attack). Т.е. вы вынудите пользователей не только сменить пароль на свой сервис, но и поменять пароль на все остальные сервисы (да, нехорошо использовать везде один и тот же пароль, но все так делают!)

Из этого прямо следуют требования к хэшированию:

1. Злодей не должен иметь возможность быстро восстановить популярные пароли по хэшу. Использование популярного MD5/SHA1 позволяет быстро восстановить пароли. `5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99` расшифрует с первого раза любой онлайновый сервис.
2. Злодей не должен иметь возможность восстановить перебором пароли для всех пользователей сразу. Один и тот же пароль, использованный разными пользователеми, должен дать разный хэш. Это увеличит время на расшифровку пропорционально количеству пользователей.

Есть надежный стандартный способ решить сразу обе проблемы - Key Derivation Function ([Функция формирования ключа](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0)).

Суть решения:

1. При первоначальном хэшировании сгенерировать рандомное значение - соль, и посчитать хэш от "соль + пароль". Использованную соль хранить как часть результата.
2. При проверке пароля - хэшировать "соль + проверяемый пароль", и сравнивать со значением, полученным в (1).

Такой подход дает разные значения даже в том случае, если один пользователь дважды использует один и тот же пароль.

В .NET есть готовые резализации KDF, например [Rfc2898DeriveBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes(v=vs.110).aspx). Используется примерно так:

Хэширование:

```
public static string HashPassword(string password)
{
    byte[] salt;
    byte[] buffer2;
    if (password == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("password");
    }
    using (Rfc2898DeriveBytes bytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, 0x10, 0x3e8))
    {
        salt = bytes.Salt;
        buffer2 = bytes.GetBytes(0x20);
    }
    byte[] dst = new byte[0x31];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(salt, 0, dst, 1, 0x10);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer2, 0, dst, 0x11, 0x20);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(dst);
}
```

Проверка

```
public static bool VerifyHashedPassword(string hashedPassword, string password)
{
    byte[] buffer4;
    if (hashedPassword == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (password == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("password");
    }
    byte[] src = Convert.FromBase64String(hashedPassword);
    if ((src.Length != 0x31) || (src[0] != 0))
    {
        return false;
    }
    byte[] dst = new byte[0x10];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(src, 1, dst, 0, 0x10);
    byte[] buffer3 = new byte[0x20];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(src, 0x11, buffer3, 0, 0x20);
    using (Rfc2898DeriveBytes bytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, dst, 0x3e8))
    {
        buffer4 = bytes.GetBytes(0x20);
    }
    return ByteArraysEqual(buffer3, buffer4);
}
```

Код взят с [enSO: ASP.NET Identity default Password Hasher, how does it work and is it secure?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20622428/1988244)

Comment: Вот, пользоваться пользовался, но расписывать стало лень, да и названия не знал конкретных алгоритмов. Автору то может и лишнее, а в целом - наиболее безопасный вариант.

Comment: Ну в одном из комментариев я написал, что один из самых действенных вариантов SSL, но не везде это реально, чтобы "скрыть" сам пароль можно воспользоваться хешом, Кстати подскажите ссылку на сервис вскрытия хешов, очень стало интересно. А вот система открытого ключа, или формирование общего ключа может решить проблему, однако что первый что второй вариант ломается промежуточным слушателем. У нас на предприятии сертификат подменяется собственным, дабы "контролировать" весь трафик.

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик нет, не ломается. У вас на предприятии подмена сертификата работает только потому, что на все рабочие машины установлен свой certificate authority, скорее всего через политики домена. Т.е. подмена работает только потому, что администратор принудительно настроил каждую машину доверять промежуточному слушателю. Это не man in the middle, а просто подтверждение факта, что админ имеет полный контроль над машиной. В интернете такое не проходит, по крайней мере пока. Из сервисов - например, http://www.md5online.org/.

Comment: @PashaPash первый же хеш No result found in our database, как и подозревал поиск уже в созданных базах хеша, декрипта как такового не существует. Максимум что Вы получите дак это аналог пароля но не его самого.

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик ну да, декрипта нет - это же хэш. Поиск по базам позволяет восстановить популярные пароли. Подбор через радужные таблицы позволяет восстановить остальные пароли (буквы+цифры). Радужные таблицы дают перебор 10^13 паролей в секунду - т.е. любой c00lpa55 подбирается мгновенно. Да, с некоторой вероятностью перебор выдаст не пароль, а коллизию - но для коротких (<10 символов) - вы почти наверняка восстановите именно сам пароль.

Answer (score 0):

На шарпе хеш можно посчитать как-нибудь так:

```
public static string GetHash(string password)
{
  using (var hash = SHA1.Create())
  {
    return string.Concat(hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password)).Select(x => x.ToString("X2")));
  }
}
```

Вместо SHA1 подойдет любой алгоритм, в том числе и MD5.

Вы должны понимать, что для злоумышленника это не задержка вообще, особенно если вы разрешаете доступ по самому хешу - тогда никакой разницы, утек пароль или его хеш.

Comment: Пожалуй самый защищенный метод это либо [Криптосистема с открытым ключом](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Криптосистема_с_открытым_ключом), либо [Электронная подпись](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Электронная_подпись). Но и они в отдельных случаях не спасают. Хотя подпись пожалуй самая надёжная, только дорогая...

Comment: @Monk можете пояснить, что значит никакой разницы, утек пароль или его хэш?. При вводе в строку пароля хэша, от него же тоже посчитается хэш. И как пароль не подойдет. А вообще, хэш-функции нужны же для того, чтобы при потере БД у злоумышленника не было доступа ко всем учетным записям.

Comment: Тут автор прав, по сути пост запросом Вы отправляете MD5, что мешает злоумышленнику подсунуть уже созданный MD5 вместо пароля, который по сути переводится в MD5 JS. Главное получить пару логинизации на сервере, ну это уже определяется криптозащитой необходимой лично Вам.

Comment: @Trymount это только пока хакер ограничен формой ввода. Но вот если хакер имеет доступ к базе, то может он и ещё к чему имеет доступ? Фактически, при доступе к базе, я уже расчитываю на худший сценарий, когда и к серверу доступ тоже есть. А значит ввести напрямую хеш, а не пароль куда надо он точно сможет.

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик асимметричное шифрование действительно выглядит лучше всего, в плане дешевых и стабильных реализаций.

Comment: @Monk если не попался промежуточный слушатель. Вот тут то и возникает проблемма. Правда внедрится шлюзом между Вами и сервером это уже не тривиальная задача. Самый простой метод шифрования это Диффи. Но использовать его для HTTP, это сложновато...

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик https + передача пароля как есть - в разы безопаснее любой самописной реализации. Не нужны тут ни электронные подписи, ни DH, ни особые знания. Поставить сертификат и забыть.

Answer (score -1):

Как вариант [MD5](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-md5/)

```
var MD5 = function (string) {

   function RotateLeft(lValue, iShiftBits) {
           return (lValue<<iShiftBits) | (lValue>>>(32-iShiftBits));
   }

   function AddUnsigned(lX,lY) {
           var lX4,lY4,lX8,lY8,lResult;
           lX8 = (lX & 0x80000000);
           lY8 = (lY & 0x80000000);
           lX4 = (lX & 0x40000000);
           lY4 = (lY & 0x40000000);
           lResult = (lX & 0x3FFFFFFF)+(lY & 0x3FFFFFFF);
           if (lX4 & lY4) {
                   return (lResult ^ 0x80000000 ^ lX8 ^ lY8);
           }
           if (lX4 | lY4) {
                   if (lResult & 0x40000000) {
                           return (lResult ^ 0xC0000000 ^ lX8 ^ lY8);
                   } else {
                           return (lResult ^ 0x40000000 ^ lX8 ^ lY8);
                   }
           } else {
                   return (lResult ^ lX8 ^ lY8);
           }
   }

   function F(x,y,z) { return (x & y) | ((~x) & z); }
   function G(x,y,z) { return (x & z) | (y & (~z)); }
   function H(x,y,z) { return (x ^ y ^ z); }
   function I(x,y,z) { return (y ^ (x | (~z))); }

   function FF(a,b,c,d,x,s,ac) {
           a = AddUnsigned(a, AddUnsigned(AddUnsigned(F(b, c, d), x), ac));
           return AddUnsigned(RotateLeft(a, s), b);
   };

   function GG(a,b,c,d,x,s,ac) {
           a = AddUnsigned(a, AddUnsigned(AddUnsigned(G(b, c, d), x), ac));
           return AddUnsigned(RotateLeft(a, s), b);
   };

   function HH(a,b,c,d,x,s,ac) {
           a = AddUnsigned(a, AddUnsigned(AddUnsigned(H(b, c, d), x), ac));
           return AddUnsigned(RotateLeft(a, s), b);
   };

   function II(a,b,c,d,x,s,ac) {
           a = AddUnsigned(a, AddUnsigned(AddUnsigned(I(b, c, d), x), ac));
           return AddUnsigned(RotateLeft(a, s), b);
   };

   function ConvertToWordArray(string) {
           var lWordCount;
           var lMessageLength = string.length;
           var lNumberOfWords_temp1=lMessageLength + 8;
           var lNumberOfWords_temp2=(lNumberOfWords_temp1-(lNumberOfWords_temp1 % 64))/64;
           var lNumberOfWords = (lNumberOfWords_temp2+1)*16;
           var lWordArray=Array(lNumberOfWords-1);
           var lBytePosition = 0;
           var lByteCount = 0;
           while ( lByteCount < lMessageLength ) {
                   lWordCount = (lByteCount-(lByteCount % 4))/4;
                   lBytePosition = (lByteCount % 4)*8;
                   lWordArray[lWordCount] = (lWordArray[lWordCount] | (string.charCodeAt(lByteCount)<<lBytePosition));
                   lByteCount++;
           }
           lWordCount = (lByteCount-(lByteCount % 4))/4;
           lBytePosition = (lByteCount % 4)*8;
           lWordArray[lWordCount] = lWordArray[lWordCount] | (0x80<<lBytePosition);
           lWordArray[lNumberOfWords-2] = lMessageLength<<3;
           lWordArray[lNumberOfWords-1] = lMessageLength>>>29;
           return lWordArray;
   };

   function WordToHex(lValue) {
           var WordToHexValue="",WordToHexValue_temp="",lByte,lCount;
           for (lCount = 0;lCount<=3;lCount++) {
                   lByte = (lValue>>>(lCount*8)) & 255;
                   WordToHexValue_temp = "0" + lByte.toString(16);
                   WordToHexValue = WordToHexValue + WordToHexValue_temp.substr(WordToHexValue_temp.length-2,2);
           }
           return WordToHexValue;
   };

   function Utf8Encode(string) {
           string = string.replace(/\r\n/g,"\n");
           var utftext = "";

           for (var n = 0; n < string.length; n++) {

                   var c = string.charCodeAt(n);

                   if (c < 128) {
                           utftext += String.fromCharCode(c);
                   }
                   else if((c > 127) && (c < 2048)) {
                           utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 6) | 192);
                           utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
                   }
                   else {
                           utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 12) | 224);
                           utftext += String.fromCharCode(((c >> 6) & 63) | 128);
                           utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
                   }

           }

           return utftext;
   };

   var x=Array();
   var k,AA,BB,CC,DD,a,b,c,d;
   var S11=7, S12=12, S13=17, S14=22;
   var S21=5, S22=9 , S23=14, S24=20;
   var S31=4, S32=11, S33=16, S34=23;
   var S41=6, S42=10, S43=15, S44=21;

   string = Utf8Encode(string);

   x = ConvertToWordArray(string);

   a = 0x67452301; b = 0xEFCDAB89; c = 0x98BADCFE; d = 0x10325476;

   for (k=0;k<x.length;k+=16) {
           AA=a; BB=b; CC=c; DD=d;
           a=FF(a,b,c,d,x[k+0], S11,0xD76AA478);
           d=FF(d,a,b,c,x[k+1], S12,0xE8C7B756);
           c=FF(c,d,a,b,x[k+2], S13,0x242070DB);
           b=FF(b,c,d,a,x[k+3], S14,0xC1BDCEEE);
           a=FF(a,b,c,d,x[k+4], S11,0xF57C0FAF);
           d=FF(d,a,b,c,x[k+5], S12,0x4787C62A);
           c=FF(c,d,a,b,x[k+6], S13,0xA8304613);
           b=FF(b,c,d,a,x[k+7], S14,0xFD469501);
           a=FF(a,b,c,d,x[k+8], S11,0x698098D8);
           d=FF(d,a,b,c,x[k+9], S12,0x8B44F7AF);
           c=FF(c,d,a,b,x[k+10],S13,0xFFFF5BB1);
           b=FF(b,c,d,a,x[k+11],S14,0x895CD7BE);
           a=FF(a,b,c,d,x[k+12],S11,0x6B901122);
           d=FF(d,a,b,c,x[k+13],S12,0xFD987193);
           c=FF(c,d,a,b,x[k+14],S13,0xA679438E);
           b=FF(b,c,d,a,x[k+15],S14,0x49B40821);
           a=GG(a,b,c,d,x[k+1], S21,0xF61E2562);
           d=GG(d,a,b,c,x[k+6], S22,0xC040B340);
           c=GG(c,d,a,b,x[k+11],S23,0x265E5A51);
           b=GG(b,c,d,a,x[k+0], S24,0xE9B6C7AA);
           a=GG(a,b,c,d,x[k+5], S21,0xD62F105D);
           d=GG(d,a,b,c,x[k+10],S22,0x2441453);
           c=GG(c,d,a,b,x[k+15],S23,0xD8A1E681);
           b=GG(b,c,d,a,x[k+4], S24,0xE7D3FBC8);
           a=GG(a,b,c,d,x[k+9], S21,0x21E1CDE6);
           d=GG(d,a,b,c,x[k+14],S22,0xC33707D6);
           c=GG(c,d,a,b,x[k+3], S23,0xF4D50D87);
           b=GG(b,c,d,a,x[k+8], S24,0x455A14ED);
           a=GG(a,b,c,d,x[k+13],S21,0xA9E3E905);
           d=GG(d,a,b,c,x[k+2], S22,0xFCEFA3F8);
           c=GG(c,d,a,b,x[k+7], S23,0x676F02D9);
           b=GG(b,c,d,a,x[k+12],S24,0x8D2A4C8A);
           a=HH(a,b,c,d,x[k+5], S31,0xFFFA3942);
           d=HH(d,a,b,c,x[k+8], S32,0x8771F681);
           c=HH(c,d,a,b,x[k+11],S33,0x6D9D6122);
           b=HH(b,c,d,a,x[k+14],S34,0xFDE5380C);
           a=HH(a,b,c,d,x[k+1], S31,0xA4BEEA44);
           d=HH(d,a,b,c,x[k+4], S32,0x4BDECFA9);
           c=HH(c,d,a,b,x[k+7], S33,0xF6BB4B60);
           b=HH(b,c,d,a,x[k+10],S34,0xBEBFBC70);
           a=HH(a,b,c,d,x[k+13],S31,0x289B7EC6);
           d=HH(d,a,b,c,x[k+0], S32,0xEAA127FA);
           c=HH(c,d,a,b,x[k+3], S33,0xD4EF3085);
           b=HH(b,c,d,a,x[k+6], S34,0x4881D05);
           a=HH(a,b,c,d,x[k+9], S31,0xD9D4D039);
           d=HH(d,a,b,c,x[k+12],S32,0xE6DB99E5);
           c=HH(c,d,a,b,x[k+15],S33,0x1FA27CF8);
           b=HH(b,c,d,a,x[k+2], S34,0xC4AC5665);
           a=II(a,b,c,d,x[k+0], S41,0xF4292244);
           d=II(d,a,b,c,x[k+7], S42,0x432AFF97);
           c=II(c,d,a,b,x[k+14],S43,0xAB9423A7);
           b=II(b,c,d,a,x[k+5], S44,0xFC93A039);
           a=II(a,b,c,d,x[k+12],S41,0x655B59C3);
           d=II(d,a,b,c,x[k+3], S42,0x8F0CCC92);
           c=II(c,d,a,b,x[k+10],S43,0xFFEFF47D);
           b=II(b,c,d,a,x[k+1], S44,0x85845DD1);
           a=II(a,b,c,d,x[k+8], S41,0x6FA87E4F);
           d=II(d,a,b,c,x[k+15],S42,0xFE2CE6E0);
           c=II(c,d,a,b,x[k+6], S43,0xA3014314);
           b=II(b,c,d,a,x[k+13],S44,0x4E0811A1);
           a=II(a,b,c,d,x[k+4], S41,0xF7537E82);
           d=II(d,a,b,c,x[k+11],S42,0xBD3AF235);
           c=II(c,d,a,b,x[k+2], S43,0x2AD7D2BB);
           b=II(b,c,d,a,x[k+9], S44,0xEB86D391);
           a=AddUnsigned(a,AA);
           b=AddUnsigned(b,BB);
           c=AddUnsigned(c,CC);
           d=AddUnsigned(d,DD);
      }

    var temp = WordToHex(a)+WordToHex(b)+WordToHex(c)+WordToHex(d);

    return temp.toLowerCase();
}
```

Использование:

```
MD5("whatever");
```

Можно воспользоваться [протоколом Диффи-Хеллмана](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB_%D0%94%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8_%E2%80%94_%D0%A5%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0). Но тут придётся налаживать общий ключ между клиентом и сервером. В принципе нет особо защищенного метода, разве что ssh, Но и он может подделываться промежуточным прокси.

Comment: C# имеет встроенную реализацию md5.

Comment: @Qwertiy насколько я понял, предлагается шифровать на клиенте, и слать на сервер хэш. Гораздо проще слать пароль как есть, но по https, и шифровать уже на сервере.

Comment: @PashaPash, тогда это бредовое и бесполезное предложение.

Comment: @Qwertiy да, видите - на нем стоит зеленая галка. Значит это - правильный ответ :)