# админ панель asp.net mvc c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Ситуация такая, собираюсь сделать админ панель для создания объектов: новых и редактирования старых, админ будет только один, то есть я не собираюсь использовать базу т.к она попросту не нужна для моей цели. 
Собираюсь поместить логин,пароль в web.config. 
Мой первый опыт в создании подобного на asp.net mvc так что есть вопросы:

1) Насколько это безопасно? 
2) Есть какой-либо способ зашифровать данные логина, пароля в файле web.config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

хранить пароль в открытом виде в web.config ни капельки не безопасно. воспользуйтесь вот этим, для шифрования пароля:
[Ссылка на ответ в другой теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/546558/238039)